# Proper way of using two or more submit buttons

Tags: php, html

1. The buttons should be in the same context (eg. CRUD or the "input name and age" type of thing).
2. They don't *necessarily* have to be in a `<form>`.

As always when there are more than one way of accomplishing the same thing, I begin to think about security risks/code reusability/code readability etc. of doing it one way rather than the other. I have been looking at many examples throughout the Interwebs and almost all of them does this in different ways.

While I understand that it may be hard to give a straight answer to this question, I ask you to consider these factors (that confuses me in which path to choose) as well:

- Should I use `<form>`s or just `<div>`s?
- Should I use more than one `<form>`?
- Should I use `<button>` instead of `<input type="submit"...>`?
- Does it make any difference what I choose if I want to use AJAX on this call?
- Maybe there are even "better" ways of achieving this than the ones I mentioned above?

For the sake of this example, let's just use two buttons - INSERT and DELETE.
Here are two examples of what I mean (NOTE: please don't mind the logic of deleting records by the numbers, these are just *examples* ;)...

**Example 1** (by value)

```
<form action="crud.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nrecords" size="3">
    <input type="submit" name="dbrecords" value="Insert records"> 
    <input type="submit" name="dbrecords" value="Delete records"> 
</form>

<?php 
    $numberofrecords = $_POST["nrecords"];

    if($_POST['dbrecords'] == 'Insert records'){
        echo "Inserting {$numberofrecords} records";
    }
    else if($_POST['dbrecords'] == 'Delete records'){
        echo "Deleting records";
    }
?>
```

**Example 2** (by name)

```
<form action="crud.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nrecords" size="3">
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert records"> 
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete records"> 
</form>

<?php
    $numberofrecords = $_POST["nrecords"];

    if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
        echo "Inserted {$numberofrecords} records"; 
    } 
    else if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        echo "Deleted records"; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use `<form>`s or just `<div>`s?

Always use a form, follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

> Should I use more than one `<form>`?

Only if you have more than one distinct set of data you want to collect (as separate tasks, if the data is related and you collect it all together, use `<fieldset>`s).

In this example,  you do not.

> Should I use `<button>` instead of `<input type="submit"...>`?

Use `<button>` if:

- You want different values and labels (this is especially useful when dealing with internationalisation).
- You don't mind it breaking in old MSIE

> Does it make any difference what I choose if I want to use AJAX on this call?

No. See above re unobtrusive JS.

Comment: Sounds like my examples were pretty spot on then. Thanks for the links, good reads!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use ajax.
The `$_POST['action']` will decide whats to do with it.

```
<form action="crud.php" method="post" class="YourForm">
    <input type="text" name="nrecords" size="3">
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert records" onclick="insert;"> 
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete records" onclick="delete;"> 
</form>

<script>
   function delete(){
        var postdata = $('form.YourForm').serialize() + "&action=delete";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'yourURL.php',
            data: postdata,
            dataType: 'json'});
        return false;
}
   function insert(){
        var postdata = $('form.YourForm').serialize() + "&action=insert";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'yourURL.php',
            data: postdata,
            dataType: 'json'});
       return false;
}
</script>
```